# File size exceed error. How to remove the file from git?

Tags: git, github

I got the following error message when I pushed my project to Github.
"File CoreMLObjectRecognition/coreMLModels/YOLOv3.mlmodel is 236.88 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB"

Then I realized the file is too large, and anyway I no longer needed the file so I did the following.

1. Deleted the file from the project
2. Added the directory(CoreMLObjectRecognition/coreMLModels/, "YOLOv3.mlmodel" was in the directory, but have been deleted.) to .gitignore since the directory will contain large files.
3. "git rm -r --cached ." and "git add ." to reflect .gitignore
4. "git ls-files" to check which files are under the control of git. "YOLOv3.mlmodel" was not on the list.
5. "git commit" but got the msg saying: "On branch main
   Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 12 commits.
   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
   nothing to commit, working tree clean"
6. "git push" to push the change to the remote repository.

Then I still get the same error:
"File CoreMLObjectRecognition/coreMLModels/YOLOv3.mlmodel is 236.88 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB"

What did I do wrong?
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case tour file was *already* tracked in past commits, try filtering it.

- [install `git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md) (python-based)
- delete any large file in your history: `git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 2M` for instance. ([content-based filtering](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_content_based_filtering))
- force push (`git push --mirror`: make sure to notify any collaborator on that repository)